# Converting hex string to hex int in python

Tags: python, hex

Lets say i have a txt file called:
`Msg.txt`

I read this with

```
Read_msg = open("Msg.txt", "r")

Hex =  Read_msg.readline()
```

This provides me with a hex string called `'0xfff'`.

Problem is that the system i work with needs a variable that is hex but also int.

If i make a variable in python that is called:

```
Hex = 0xfff
```

Then it is fine, but i need to be able to extract this data from a txt or excel. (if you do `type()` on this variable then it ses int even if it is hex.)

I tried converting the string with:

```
Hex = int(Hex, 16)

Hex = hex(Hex)
```

But this makes it into a string again.
Is what i'm looking for even possible?

Comment: Just use `Hex = int(Hex, 16)`.  Then stop.  It's now an `int`.  Don't do `Hex = hex(Hex)`, which will convert it back into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As you can see in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) `hex()` function returns a string:

> hex(x) Convert an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string
> prefixed with “0x”.

If you simply assign hex value to a variable it becomes just a regular integer:

```
>>> a = 0xfff
>>> a
4095
```

You can use `hex()` function to then see that integer in hex format again:

```
>>> hex(a)
'0xfff'
```

The data itself is stored in binary so there is no such a thing as hex int or decimal integer, because (obviously) they are all actually binary.

Comment: I legit sat all day trying to sort this out and no matter how many prints i took to look at the problem from different views it never occured to me to actually just print the "a = 0xfff" out to see that i just got a decimal number hahaha. Thanks for the good explanation!